# Issues with postgres id generation and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, hibernate-annotations

For some reason when I insert to database from application id is always 0. This is table used for spring security auth table users, copied from pgadmin II:

```
 id serial NOT NULL,
  username character varying(100),
  password character varying(200),
  groupfk integer,
  CONSTRAINT users_pk PRIMARY KEY (id ),
  CONSTRAINT users_groupfk_fkey FOREIGN KEY (groupfk)
  REFERENCES groups (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

I have a following in my User domain class, relevant ID part :

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "serial")
    @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "groupfk")
public Group getGroup() {
    return group;
}

public void setGroup(Group group) {
    this.group = group;
}
```

So I'm inserting user like this :

```
User user = new User();
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setUsername(username);

        Group group = new Group();
        group.setId(usergroup);
        user.setGroup(group);
                dao.saveUser(user);
```

Dao method impl :

```
public void save(User user) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(user);
    }
```

So here is the exception I get :

```
Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into users (groupfk, password, username, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

Real query :

```
Batch entry 0 insert into users (groupfk, password, username, id) values ('1', '098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6', 'test3', '0') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
```

So I inserted previous user with id `0` and it was successful. And I tried to insert another one but because it had the same ID this error occurred.

Normally if I try to insert it with sql trough sql client (pgadmin) it works, this works as expected :

```
insert into users (username, password, groupfk) VALUES ('test', 'c20ad4d76fe97759aa27a0c99bff6710',1);
```

So hibernate for some reason doesn't generate my id appropriately, the truth is if the above statement is working it shouldn't generate it at all.

What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ID should be an `Integer`, not an `int`.  Everytime you create an instance of your class, it initializes the value of `this.id` to 0.  Hibernate then will think of this object as already being persisted, but disconnected.  You want it to be treated as transient, which is indicated by having a null ID.  See a discussion of [Hibernate objects states in the manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html).

When you `session.save(user)`, Hibernate will see the ID is null, realize the object is transient, generate an ID for it, and save it.

Comment: You'll also want to use the `IDENTITY` generation strategy, rather than `AUTO`.

Comment: @CraigRinger I think that Postgres wants SEQUENCE if you're going to specify it, not IDENTITY.  See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id .  If you don't specify I believe Hibernate would pick SEQUENCE for a Postgres dialect.

Comment: I was referring to the JPA identity annotations since that's what the post used. In JPA, `IDENTITY` will use the DB's identity column (serial in PostgreSQL). If you use `SEQUENCE` then Hibernate uses a shared `hibernate_sequence` unless you also define a `SequenceGenerator` for each identity column and override its fetch size. That's unnecessary verbose compared to just using `IDENTITY` for the same effect.

Comment: Now, if Hibernate is the only application using the database it might be ok to use the shared `hibernate_sequence` - but in that case you should use `integer` columns not `serial` to remove confusion and unused sequences.